# React-hook-form, Zod. What is the recommended way of handling image uploads in a form that supports both adding and editing?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, react-hook-form, zod

What is the recommended way of handling image uploads in a form that supports both adding and editing of a product? Here is my current implementation with two options, is there any suggestion to improve it?

Here is the first option when an image converts to the File object and sets it as the default value for the image in the form:

```js
const getFileFromUrl = async (url: string) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const blob = await res.blob();
  return new File([blob], 'image', { type: blob.type });
};

const productForm1Schema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1, { message: 'Name is required' }),
  image: z
    .custom<File>((v) => v instanceof File, {
      message: 'Image is required',
    })
});

export type ProductForm1Values = z.infer<typeof productForm1Schema>;

interface ProductForm1Props {
  product?: Product;
}

export const ProductForm1 = ({ product }: ProductForm1Props) => {
  const isAddMode = !product;

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    watch,
    reset,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting, isDirty },
  } = useForm<ProductForm1Values>({
    resolver: zodResolver(productForm1Schema),
    defaultValues: product
      ? async () => ({
          name: product.name,
          image: await getFileFromUrl(product.image),
        })
      : {
          name: '',
          image: undefined,
        },
  });

  const image = watch('image');
  const imagePreview = image ? URL.createObjectURL(image) : null;

  // revoke object URL to avoid memory leaks
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (imagePreview) URL.revokeObjectURL(imagePreview);
    };
  }, [imagePreview]);

  const onSubmitHandler = async (data: ProductForm1Values) => {
    console.log(data);

    // build FormData for uploading image
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', data.image);

    // mock upload image to server to get image url
    const imageUrl = await new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
      }, 1000);
    });

    if (isAddMode) {
      // create product
      console.log({ ...data, image: imageUrl });
    } else {
      // update product
      console.log({ id: product!.id, ...data, image: imageUrl });
    }

    reset();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
      <input {...register('name')} />
      {errors.name && <span>{errors.name.message}</span>}

      <Controller
        name="image"
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { ref, name, onBlur, onChange } }) => (
          <input
            type="file"
            ref={ref}
            name={name}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.files?.[0])}
          />
        )}
      />
      {imagePreview && <img src={imagePreview} alt="preview" />}
      {errors.image && <span>{errors.image.message}</span>}

      <button type="submit" disabled={(!isAddMode && !isDirty) || isSubmitting}>
        {isSubmitting ? 'Submitting...' : 'Submit'}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

OR

Here is the second option when I created two schemas for creating and updating products and in the update schema image is optional:

```js
const createProductSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1, { message: 'Name is required' }),
  image: z
    .custom<File>((v) => v instanceof File, {
      message: 'Image is required',
    })
});

const updateProductSchema = createProductSchema.extend({
  image: createProductSchema.shape.image.optional(),
});

export type ProductForm2Values =
  | z.infer<typeof createProductSchema>
  | z.infer<typeof updateProductSchema>;

interface ProductForm2Props {
  product?: Product;
}

export const ProductForm2 = ({ product }: ProductForm2Props) => {
  const [imagePreview, setImagePreview] = useState<string | null>(
    product ? product.image : null,
  );

  const isAddMode = !product;

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    reset,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting, isDirty },
  } = useForm<ProductForm2Values>({
    resolver: zodResolver(
      isAddMode ? createProductSchema : updateProductSchema,
    ),
    defaultValues: {
      name: product?.name ?? '',
      image: undefined,
    },
  });

  // revoke object URL to avoid memory leaks
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (imagePreview) URL.revokeObjectURL(imagePreview);
    };
  }, [imagePreview]);

  const onSubmitHandler = async (data: ProductForm2Values) => {
    console.log(data);

    let imageUrl: string | undefined;
    if (data.image) {
      // build FormData for uploading image
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', data.image);

      // mock upload image to server to get image url
      imageUrl = await new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
        }, 1000);
      });
    }

    if (isAddMode) {
      // create product
      console.log({ ...data, image: imageUrl! });
    } else {
      // update product
      console.log({ id: product!.id, ...data, image: imageUrl });
    }

    reset();
    setImagePreview(product?.image ?? null);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
      <input {...register('name')} />
      {errors.name && <span>{errors.name.message}</span>}

      <Controller
        name="image"
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { ref, name, onBlur, onChange } }) => (
          <input
            type="file"
            ref={ref}
            name={name}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChange={(e) => {
              const file = e.target.files?.[0];
              onChange(e.target.files?.[0]);
              setImagePreview(file ? URL.createObjectURL(file) : null);
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
      {imagePreview && <img src={imagePreview} alt="preview" />}
      {errors.image && <span>{errors.image.message}</span>}

      <button type="submit" disabled={(!isAddMode && !isDirty) || isSubmitting}>
        {isSubmitting ? 'Submitting...' : 'Submit'}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: I kind of like the second approach better honestly